# How to quickly anonymize all annotations in evince?

Tags: pdf, evince, annotation

In Evince, I know that I can do right-click on the annotation -> Annotation Properties... and clear the author in the properties window. However, doing this for each annotation is overkill.

Is there a simple way to anonymize all annotations on Evince?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in evince. You can use a small python library called pymupdf to do that. Here's a small script.

```
try:
    import fitz
except ImportError as e:
    import subprocess
    print('Trying to install pip install PyMuPDF')
    subprocess.call("pip install PyMuPDF".split())
    print('Try pip install PyMuPDF')
    raise
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    raise ValueError("Please provide a pdf to anonymize")
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    outfilename = filename.replace('.pdf', '.anon.pdf')
else:
    outfilename = sys.argv[2]
filename = sys.argv[1]
doc = fitz.open(filename)
metadata = doc.metadata
for k, v in metadata.items():
    if k not in ['format']: # retain some metadata
        metadata[k] = ''
doc.set_metadata(metadata)

for page in doc:
    for annot in page.annots():
        info = annot.info
        info['title'] = ''
        annot.set_info(info)
        annot.update()

doc.save(outfilename)
```

Link to source gist:
https://gist.github.com/wecacuee/f1e92d421312b7c7c1907667f4f3a318

Comment: It's been a while since I had the issue, so I couldn't test this solution. If anyone report a positive result, I'll be happy to mark as the correct answer :)